# RabbitMq-mqtt-plugin publishing messages in batches

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, publish-subscribe

I am using rabbitmq-mqtt plugin to publish 1 million messages, but it is taking too many hours to publish messages. So, I want to publish messages in batches or to use batch confirm. I am using Eclipse Paho java client. I am new to rabbitmq. How to use batch confirm in rabbitmq-mqtt plugin? Is there any option available on management ui?

Strategy #2: Publishing Messages in Batches To improve upon our previous example, we can publish a batch of messages and wait for this whole batch to be confirmed. The following example uses a batch of 100:

```
int batchSize = 100;
int outstandingMessageCount = 0;
while (thereAreMessagesToPublish()) {
    byte[] body = ...;
    BasicProperties properties = ...;
    channel.basicPublish(exchange, queue, properties, body);
    outstandingMessageCount++;
    if (outstandingMessageCount == batchSize) {
        channel.waitForConfirmsOrDie(5_000);
        outstandingMessageCount = 0;
    }
}
if (outstandingMessageCount > 0) {
    channel.waitForConfirmsOrDie(5_000);
}
```

Waiting for a batch of messages to be confirmed improves throughput drastically over waiting for a confirm for individual message (up to 20-30 times with a remote RabbitMQ node). One drawback is that we do not know exactly what went wrong in case of failure, so we may have to keep a whole batch in memory to log something meaningful or to re-publish the messages. And this solution is still synchronous, so it blocks the publishing of messages.

This is from rabbitmq doccumentation.

What I am asking is: Is there any way to do this in rabbitmq-mqtt plugin ie instead of sending confirmation for each message arrived in queue send a confirmation for 100 messages .

I want batch publishing for rabbitmq-mqtt plugin.

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is off topic for Stack Overflow. But there is no such thing as what you are asking for, there is no way to batch delivering messages in MQTT. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74528707/edit) the question to give more details (e.g. the code) you are using to publish the messages and we may be able to offer some improvelments.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.